# Jenkins not able to fetch code from remote git repository

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I installed jenkins in ec2 instance.This is first project I am trying to build I am getting error

```
FailedConsole Output
Started by user nithinroyal
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
using credential github
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/nithinkota/demo.git/
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:957)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:737)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1105)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1145)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1205)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2379)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2298)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1857)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:955)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/demo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:936)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:454)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2365)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 21 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

While configuring project in **Source code management** step when I add repository url showing error in red colour

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git ls-remote -h https://github.com/nithinkota/demo.git/ HEAD
```

Comment: What does the "caused by" section of your stack trace say?

Comment: @Marvin I updated entire log

Comment: Do you have git installed?

Comment: I removed and installed git again working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you have installed the Jenkins Git plugins, if you have configured in the `System` page, the `Path to Git executable` field.

Put in it `C:\Path\to\Git\bin\git.exe`, with `C:\Path\to\Git` being the folder where you have installed [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).